# Twin problems with Chrome and Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, ms-security-essentials

Woke up today and am getting this error from gmail:

> The webpage at
>   https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva%3D1&ss=1&scc=1&authuser=0&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2
>   has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this
>   site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it
>   is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your
>   computer.
>
> Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this webpage later.
>   Learn more about this problem.
>   Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Meanwhile, when I try to update MSE it won't (however it doesn't give an error message).

The suggestions provided by gmail do not work, and gmail works fine on other computers on my network. I would appreciate help, and also advice on whether the problems are likely to be connected.

Comment: This sounds like malware if your unable to update MSE.

Comment: clear your dns cache
`ipconfig /flushdns` and try if it works

Comment: I occasionally get those redirect errors on various urls on any PC using chrome, I just try again later and it connects, systems are clean of malware also. They are rare but do happen for no apparent reason. Clearing cache and cookies does nothing to help.

Comment: If you suspect an infection, [see this](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533#157533)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the computer had been set to an incorrect time zone. After I fixed that, everything worked perfectly.